# jquery to .hide tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to hide tabs inside an accordion and I am trying to use jQuery to do it. Right now the html is as follows:

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <dd class="active"><a href="#p1a">Study Sheets</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#p1b">Study Sheets Answer Keys</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#p1c">Graded Assignments</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#p1d">Graded Assignment Answer Keys</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="p1a">
        <ul class="ss">
            <li><a ...ect
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="p1b">
        <ul class="ssa">
            <li><a ....ect
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>       
</div>  
</dd>
</dl>
```

How can I select the dl dd tabs for study sheets answer keys and graded assignment answer keys with jQuery?

I was thinking something like:

```
$(".tabs dd#p1b").hide();
```

But I realized I can't use ids because there are many tabs per page all with unique ids so I need to select maybe via inner html or something similar, just not sure how? Thanks

Comment: `$(".tabs dd a").hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$(".tabs dd").not(".active").hide();
```

Comment: this just hides all tabs except the active one. Ijust want to hide the 2 tabs consistently.

Comment: You could add a class "keysTab" to the dd elements you want to hide and then do this: $("dd.keysTab").hide()

Comment: is there a way to use jquery to hide an element by inner html or something? I dont want to add classes because i have to do that to a TON of html and it would defeat the purpose of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I guess then you'll have to loop through all of the dd elements and find the ones you want to hide.  $("dd").each(function(){ var a = $(this).find("a"); if(a.text() == 'Study Sheets Answer Keys' || a.text() == 'Graded Assignment Answer Keys') $(this).hide();});

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using bootstrap?
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
I believe this was the look you were going for. It is pretty simple to integrate into your website.